# Using NERDCommenter

Tags: vim, pathogen

The tutorial gives this example:

```
<leader>c$ |NERDComEOLComment|
Comments the current line from the cursor to the end of line.
```

But pressing `\c$` or `,c$` in vim copies the current line and switched to insert mode.

I've installed the plugin via pathogen and `:help nerdcommenter` does work, but there's no mention of nerdcommenter in the output of `:scripts`, don't know if that means the plugin hasn't been successfully installed.

Comment: Did you change your leader? (`:echo mapleader`) Does anything else change the binding? (`:map <leader>c$`) Do you delay between keypresses? (`:set timeoutlen?`)

Comment: `:echo mapleader` doesn't output anything; I haven't added anything related to nerdcommenter to my `.vimrc`. `:map <leader>c$` outputs `n <Space>c$    <Plug>NERDCommenterToEOL`; delay between keypresses is <1000ms of `timeoutlen`.

Comment: All seems to be in order then; in particular, NERDCommenter did load (otherwise `<leader>c$` would not have a mapping). I don't use NERDCommenter so I can't tell you why it's not doing what you expect it to do :(

Comment: NERDCommenter's issue tracker is [that way](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/issues).

Answer (score 1):

This looks fine. Here are some troubleshooting tips:

1. Check the `:scriptnames` output for `.../plugin/NERD_commenter.vim`; it needs to be there.
2. Check `:echo loaded_nerd_comments`
3. Check `:echo g:NERDCreateDefaultMappings`
4. Check `:nmap <Leader>c`
5. Do other mappings work? Define `:nmap <Leader>x :echomsg "Works"<CR>` and press `\x`.
6. If mappings don't work, you may have accidentally `:set paste`. Undo with `:set nopaste`.

Comment: Thank you for posting this!